# Servo and power supply problems

Tags: arduino, power-supply, servo, torque

I'm new to Arduino so baby language for me please :)

Problem: I'm trying to power 2 servos (https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07DQFXDC9/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
but there's only 1 5v pin on my Uno.

The project involves making two servos move when I hold down a button (also coming from the 5V and has a resistor in series).

I've tried two things to make this work:

1. Powering both servos from the 5v pin. The motors are slightly weaker than I'd like and if I hold down the button for a few seconds, the motors glitch, the computer makes the disconnect sound and the arduino restarts.
2. Powering both servos from an external 9v battery. Both motors are MUCH weaker than when just one was plugged into the 5v and theyre unusable like that for this project.

Any help is massively appreciated and feel free to dumb it down for me haha

Comment: What is the project?

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't that you only have one 5v pin, the problem is that you are exceeding the half-ampere current limitation of the USB specification, and causing some sort of protective circuit in your PC to activate - fortunately that is happening, otherwise you would damage the port.

Something like a phone "charger" used on its own may give you a bit more power as these are often willing to supply an ampere or two to a phone that figures out it is plugged into a charger and not a computer, and so draws more to charge its battery faster.

> Powering both servos from an external 9v battery.

That's doubly problematic, first because it is will outside the allowed voltage range, but next because while the designed voltage into a light load is high, the available *current* is far too low to properly operate a servo.

You need a high current 5v supply, not a high voltage low current supply.

Comment: thanks for this answer, it actually makes a lot of sense!. How can I find the power supply I need and how much current to look for? Also, the arduino will eventually not be plugged in to the computer so I'm assuming i will still need the 9v plugged into it's socket in the arduino?

Comment: That's not a simple situation.  Hobby servos are made to run from 4 AA cells, but your Arduino's regulator needs more.  One solution could be a 3.3 volt 8 MHz Arduino.  Or you could use 6 cells to feed the Arduino's DC input jack, and 4 to run the motors directly.  Whatever you do, do not run the motors on the Arduino's voltage regulator.  RC aircraft with high voltage high current propellor-motor batteries would typical use a "battery eliminator" high current regulator to run their servos.

Comment: I've just had a look and all the 5v power supplies need to be plugged into the wall but I need this to be battery operated. Is this not possible to do?

Comment: ah, I've just seen that last response. So to summarise, I can't power them even weakly with the 5v pin, i need to find an external battery supply that has 6 cells (but wouldn't that have too much voltage?)

Comment: would one option be to have two 4-cells of AA each connected to one servo, plus a 9v to power the arduino?

Comment: Please re-read the above explanation of cell counts: 6 for the arduino regulator's input 4 for the servos.  You don't want to use a 9v battery to run an Arduino as it will die in notime.